# Typography component from react Material-UI weird API

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

as seen [here](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/) the api of the Typography component includes both gutterBottom and paragraph. both seem the same: "false  If true, the text will have a bottom margin."
What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment with my reputation but I am unsure if this qualifies as an answer. I just tested it and the only difference I saw was that the paragraph attribute did add more bottomMargin than the gutterBottom attribute. However in my example it made like a 5px difference between the two.